# Values of the complex power $1^\sqrt{2}$

Tags: complex-numbers

I have to show that the values of the complex power $1^\sqrt{2}$ all lie on the unit circle, i.e. that $|1^\sqrt{2}|=1$.

$1^\sqrt{2} = e ^ {\sqrt{2} \ln{1}}$ by definition, and $\ln{1} = 2k \pi i$ with $ k\in \mathbb{Z}$, so $1^\sqrt{2} = e ^ {2 \sqrt{2} k \pi i} = e ^ {2 \sqrt{2} k} e ^{\pi i} = e^{2 \sqrt{2} k} ( \cos \pi + i \sin \pi ) = e^{2 \sqrt{2} k}$ by Euler's formula, but these complex numbers definitely do *not* lie on the unit circle. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $e^{2\sqrt2 k \pi i} \ne e^{2\sqrt2k}e^{\pi i}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$e^{ab} \neq e^a e^b$. The latter equals $e^{a+b}$, not $e^{ab}$.

Comment: Oh that is a really silly mistake. Thanks. Shall I delete this?

Comment: No, leave it. It might help others.

Comment: @Bart See? It has 70 views already. Someone might've been helped by it.

Comment: @SkeletonBow Or all those people wasted their time, ha!

Comment: @Bart right, it's still quite interesting :)